# How to display different icons for tray icon and notification popup icon in windows

Tags: python, windows

Is there any way to display different icons in system tray and in notification popup for a python application?

I am using module 'ctypes' and Shell_NotifyIconW to display the notification popup. The tray icon is displayed fine and the same icon is getting displayed in the notification popup also. I need to display a different icon in notification popup.

Also, noticed that 'applicationname'.exe text is getting displayed in the notification popup. Is there any method to remove this text?

Comment: [Shell_NotifyIconW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx) takes the PNOTIFYICONDATA argument which has a `hIcon` member to specify the Icon. How are you calling Shell_NotifyIconW and does specifying the icon not work as expected  ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I am using Shell_NotifyIconW() available in ctypes.windll python module for displaying the notification popup. Even on assigning a hIcon argument to NOTIFYICONDATA, it will display the tray icon as notification popup icon.